# Add/Keep a query string to every a link on current domain if one exists

Tags: javascript

I'm quite limited in what I can do so cookies & local_storage isn't an option unfortunately.

I am looking for a solution to keep a specific query string available on every page on the website...

Lets say the query string is: **`?keepme=true`**

I assume the best way would be to modify every `<a>` tag that has a URL to the current domain and modify the link to include the query string?

Any advise would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have backend access? You can potentially get query params from the request and return them to the front end.

Comment: Unfortunately not, only javascript/jquery access.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a script on `DOMContentLoaded` event and add the string to all anchor tags

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e) {
  var anchortags = document.querySelectorAll("a");
  anchortags.forEach(function(tag) {
      if(tag.hostname == 'stackoverflow.com' || tag.hostname == ''){
        tag.href = tag.href + '&keepme=true';
      }          
  });
}, false);
```

Comment: But that would also append them to external sites, it must only be the current domain

Comment: Updated the answer. You can check if the url contains your domain name

Comment: I just found one problem with that, if the URL is simply `<a href="/this-is-a-page-on-current-domain/">link</a>` it doesn't work... :/

Comment: You can check using hostname. See the updated answer

Comment: That works really well for all of the normal links that are on the page but we have some links that render after the DOMContent loads that have a query string on them already: `website.com/?string=sdjsijd#all`

Comment: You should extract the queryparms and form the url again in that case.

Comment: yeah I tried something similar, I tried to replace the #all with nothing and then append the `&keepme=true#all` but it complains about it being an unexpected string. I had even added like 20 different `#all`, `#more`, `#detail`, `#list` but I've probably missed some of those too :(

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check keepme variable in all page at client side, you can use `localstorage` instead of query string.

If the keepme variable need to process in server side, you should use `session` for storing value.

If you want to add manually to query string use can do like this.

```js
function addOrUpdateQueryStringParameter(uri, key, value) {
  var re = new RegExp("([?&])" + key + "=.*?(&|$)", "i");
  var separator = uri.indexOf('?') !== -1 ? "&" : "?";
  if (uri.match(re)) {
    return uri.replace(re, '$1' + key + "=" + value + '$2');
  }
  else {
    return uri + separator + key + "=" + value;
  }
}

console.log(addOrUpdateQueryStringParameter('/test-url','keepme', true))
```

Comment: Yeah localstorage is a no go :( we only need the query string to be available in the URL of every page on the current website. Either appending it to all `a` links or intercepting the link click or something like that